# Adding the data in two-Dimensional list using two single List

Tags: apex

I have two lists on accounts having the same data and I wanted to make another two-dimensional list and add the Data of the Two lists into the Two-dimensional list.

```
List<List<Account>> lstAcc = new List<List<Account>>();
List<Account> lstAcc1 = new List<Account>();
List<Account> lstAcc2 = new List<Account>();
 lstAcc1 = [select id,name from Account];
for(Account acc : lstAcc1){
    lstAcc2.add(acc);
}

System.debug('lstAcc1>>'+lstAcc1);
System.debug('lstAcc2>>'+lstAcc2);
```

Comment: I don't think your question is very clear, and it sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). A nested List is the solution that you've chosen, but what is the problem that your nested List is supposed to solve? You should [edit] your question to better explain the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Derek mentioned, not sure why you need this and how you will use this `List<List<Account>>`, but if it is just for your learning, as mentioned by @David, you should go through the [List Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm) to get further information on this.

And as far as your requirement is concerned, you can simply add the `List<Account>` to your `List<List<Account>>` like the way you are adding `Account` to `List<Account>` i.e. the method still remains the same

```
lstAcc.add(lstAcc1);
lstAcc.add(lstAcc2);
```

These above lines will add two `List<Account>` elements into `List<List<Account>>` variable.

**Note :** This is just to explain you on how to add elements to nested list and not to solve your broader problem which you haven't explained yet. I am assuming that it is just for your learning purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Either you expand the list via addAll (see [List Class of the Apex Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)) or you use a Map (see [Map Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm)).

In your case you would most likely use `Map<ID,sObject>(recordList)`, or for two-dimensional data `map(list<Id, sObject>, list<Id, sObject>)`